# I not able to connect to ibm bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, arduino-uno, watson-iot

This is the code that has been used. The IP that is used is on the same WiFi network to which my laptop is connected. Only the last digit is different.

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include<SPI.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

byte mac[] = { 0x12, 0xED, 0xBA, 0xFE, 0x2E, 0xED };
String macstr="12edbafe2eed";
byte ip[] = {192,16,1,1};
EthernetClient ethClient;

char servername[]="99elnd.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com";
PubSubClient client(servername, 1883,ethClient);

   void setup()
 { 
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial.println("Arduino MQTT v.1.2");
 Ethernet.begin(mac,ip);
 }

void loop()
 {
char clientStr[33]; 
String clientName = String("d:99elnd:arduno_mitul:12edbafe2ee2");
clientName.toCharArray(clientStr,33);
char token[] = "mituliot7450";
 while (!client.connected()) {
Serial.println("Reconnecting client … ");
client.connect(clientStr, "use-token-auth", token);
}

 String data = "{\"d\": {\"TEST\":";
       data+=random(10);
       data+="} }";

         char jsonStr[33];
       data.toCharArray(jsonStr,33);
    char topicStr[33];
         String topicName = String("iot-2/evt/status/fmt/json");
       topicName.toCharArray(topicStr,33);
        Serial.print("attempt to send");
          Serial.print(jsonStr);
       Serial.print("to");
         Serial.println(topicStr);
          if (client.publish(topicStr,jsonStr))
        Serial.println("successfully sent");
         else
          Serial.println("unsuccessfully sent");
         Serial.println("Disconnecting client … ");
           client.disconnect();
          delay(5000);
          }
```

The serial monitor prints:

```
Arduino MQTT v.1.2
Reconnecting client â€¦
Reconnecting client â€¦
Reconnecting client â€¦
Reconnecting client â€¦
Reconnecting client â€¦
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Your question may get flagged for closing because it probably doesn't meet the stackoverflow criteria.  See here for more information http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: You don't see "Arduino MQTT v.1.2" in your output either, as per your Serial.println? I don't have an env to test this but I'd get rid of the spaces/tabs before the void setup().

Comment: Sorry for the wrong information.  It is shown

Comment: Is 12edbafe2ee2 the name of the actual registered device you see in the Watson IoT Platform, and it has type arduno_mitul?

Comment: yes....this is the information used to create my device on ibm watson

Comment: Dunno, looks good to me.  You could add some debug, make sure the internet connectivity from arduino is working.  Maybe a firewall blocking on port 1883. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ClientConnected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its slightly strange you are using 192,16,1,1 as your IP.  Typically x.x.x.1 is the default gateway for a given network.  If that is the case in your network, then there will be an IP conflict and your device will not have Internet connectivity.  This appears to be the case as the credentials from your sketch do work, but there is no record of that device ever even attempting to connect prior to my testing.

You could use DHCP instead which is probably more portable as in the hello world client example here:

http://www.tweaking4all.com/hardware/arduino/arduino-ethernet-data-pull/

or try using the IP address of your laptop (while that is disconnected of course) if indeed your laptop is also using static IP assignment.  I've found that, if the gateway and the DHCP server are one and the same device, it will not route traffic for an IP it has not supplied via DHCP, even if it is a valid and unused IP address.  You have to limit the range of addresses the DHCP server can dish out in order to free up some to be used in static assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like maybe you are passing the wrong token for authentication - I see some authentication errors in the Watson-IoT log.  Please confirm you are passing the correct authentication token that was generated when you registered the device.

Comment: Thank you and I will try it once again.

Comment: I have changed the device id and have given the correct token. But still the same response. The device ID is : feeddeadbafe  @ValerieLampkin